# Is it possible to have a remote sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

Can you store an sqlite database remotely on a server? I am building an iphone app and all the tutorials seem to store the sqlite database on the iphone itself...

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I think if you want to do this you need to write your own "server" app that is on the remove machine and wraps around the SQLite database. Update: Actually, there *are* alternatives, see: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: pls, put it as answer, so it can be voted/accepted.

Comment: @Sunny: I didn't post as an answer because I'm not really certain of this (having never tried or researched it myself), I just searched the web for "sqlite remote" and put in the first link I got. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not advisable, as you will quickly run into concurrency problems.  I would use a traditional RDMS such as MySQL or PostegreSQL in such a case.

SQLite has a [useful page](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) explaining when to use it.  It says:

> If you have many client programs
>   accessing a common database over a
>   network, you should consider using a
>   client/server database engine instead
>   of SQLite.

Comment: I think the SQLite document is saying that they don't recommend using a network filesystem to share the database across the network.

Comment: I don't think this reply is quite right (anymore)? The general guideline (echoed by the link in the reply) is that SQLite seems to work just great for Internet exposed databases of many scenarios, as long as they are not write-heavy.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Matthew Flaschen, but if you really want to, you can connect to a sqlite db throuth an ssh tunnel. If multiple clients prefer mysql postgresql.