# Is SQLite a local database?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a code that creates a database upon registering into an application with `CREATE TABLE` etc. and then I insert the user to the database. Though will this data be available to another user who registered on his own device or is the database local ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494252/is-it-possible-to-have-a-remote-sqlite-database

Comment: It's local to the phone. If you need it accessed else where you need to use a web server and upload it to there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An sqlite database is just a file, stored locally in your device.